# How to deselect just the button `Select all` not all items?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a `checkbox` to Select All/Deselect All Items from a `checkedListBox`. Fore this I have the next code who works:

```
 private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)

                checkBox1.Checked = true;
            else if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
}
```

But the problem is, If I have all items checked (the button `select all` is checked) and If I make click on one item all are deselected (and the button `select all` is uncheck ). I want when I make click on one item to deselect just the button `Select all` not all items?

EDIT:
Here is my code :

```
private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            string installerfilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "installer.ini");
            IEnumerable<string> inilines = File.ReadAllLines(installerfilename).AsEnumerable();

           /* string selectedItem = checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            bool IsChecked = checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains(selectedItem);*/
            bool IsChecked = 

    checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Contains(checkedListBox2.SelectedItem);

                if (IsChecked)
                    inilines = inilines.Select(line => line == string.Format("#product={0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem)
                                                       ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format("#product={0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem), string.Format(@"product={0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem))
                                                       : line);

                else
                    inilines = inilines.Select(line => (line == string.Format("product={0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem))
                                                       ? Regex.Replace(line, string.Format(@".*product={0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem), string.Format(@"#product={0}", checkedListBox2.SelectedItem))
                                                       : line);

                if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
                    inilines = inilines.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @".*product=all", @"product=all"));
                else
                    inilines = inilines.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @".*product=all", @"#product=all"));


                if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)           
                    checkBox1.Checked = true; 
                else if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
                    checkBox1.Checked = false;


                string strWrite = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inilines.ToArray());
                File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, strWrite);

            }

     private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
                string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
                var lin = File.ReadLines(path + "installer.ini").ToArray();

                CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
                if ((cb.Checked) && (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count))
                {
                                 //  checkBox1.Checked = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true)                    
                        }
                    foreach (var txt in lin)
                    {
                        if (txt.Contains("#product="))
                        {
                            // var name = txt.Split('=')[1];
                            installertext = installertext.Replace("#product=", "product=");
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
                    }
                }
                    else if ((!cb.Checked) && ((checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count) || (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)))
                    {

                        //checkBox1.Checked = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, false);                            
                        }
                        foreach (var txt in lin)
                        {

                            if (txt.Contains("product=") && (!txt.StartsWith("#")))
                            {
                                // var name1 = txt.Split('=')[1];
                                installertext = installertext.Replace(txt, "#" +txt);
                            }
                            File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
                        }
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Is "select all" checkbox outside of `CheckedListBox` control?

Comment: yes, I have "private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {" after that

Comment: Your code is working fine !!!  set CheckOnClick as True for CheckedList box and try again !!!

Comment: What is the code for `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` ?

Comment: I already do this, but after this row  checkBox1.Checked = false; salt at "checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { " and I don't want this

Comment: @samaneh the code for checkBox1_CheckedChanged is to select/ deselect all, but I don't want to salt there

Comment: all I want is to check and don't do what is in checkBox1_CheckedChanged

Comment: comment your code in checkBox1_CheckedChanged event and check

Comment: seriously?? but I need that code, because I want to select/ deselect all but when I make click on that button

Comment: My bad !!! add below one line of code to your existing  checkBox1_CheckedChanged event code:    if (this.ActiveControl.Name !="checkBox1" ) return;      //you code goes here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a `boolean` field to determine whether user manually checked the `CheckBox` or it gets checked by the `checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` method. Then only check/uncheck all items when this field is `true`. Something like the following code should work:

```
    bool _checkedManually = true;

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_checkedManually)
        {
            _checkedManually = true;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked)
                checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            else
                checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, false);
        }
    }

    private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _checkedManually = false;

        if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
        else if (checkedListBox2.CheckedItems.Count != checkedListBox2.Items.Count)
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
```

**Update:**

As Rakesh mentioned in the comments, just add this line `if(this.ActiveControl != sender ) return;` to your `checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1` method:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string installerfilename = path + "installer.ini";
                string installertext = File.ReadAllText(installerfilename);
                var lin = File.ReadLines(path + "installer.ini").ToArray();

                if(this.ActiveControl != sender )
                    return;

                CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
                if ((cb.Checked)
                {
                                 //  checkBox1.Checked = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                        {
                            this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true)                    
                        }
                    foreach (var txt in lin)
                    {
                        if (txt.Contains("#product="))
                        {
                            // var name = txt.Split('=')[1];
                            installertext = installertext.Replace("#product=", "product=");
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
                    }
                }
                else 
                {

                    //checkBox1.Checked = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, false);                            
                    }
                    foreach (var txt in lin)
                    {

                        if (txt.Contains("product=") && (!txt.StartsWith("#")))
                        {
                            // var name1 = txt.Split('=')[1];
                            installertext = installertext.Replace(txt, "#" +txt);
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText(installerfilename, installertext);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: I edited my post and now you can see my code. You can help me now??